# Is there a way to calculate correlation in TSQL using OVER Clauses instead of CTE's?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, correlation

Let's say you have a table with columns, Date, GroupID, X and Y.

```
CREATE TABLE #sample
  (
     [Date]  DATETIME,
     GroupID INT,
     X       FLOAT,
     Y       FLOAT
  )

DECLARE @date DATETIME = getdate()

INSERT INTO #sample VALUES(@date, 1, 1,3)
INSERT INTO #sample VALUES(DATEADD(d, 1, @date), 1, 1,1)
INSERT INTO #sample VALUES(DATEADD(d, 2, @date), 1, 4,2)
INSERT INTO #sample VALUES(DATEADD(d, 3, @date), 1, 3,3)
INSERT INTO #sample VALUES(DATEADD(d, 4, @date), 1, 6,4)
INSERT INTO #sample VALUES(DATEADD(d, 5, @date), 1, 7,5)
INSERT INTO #sample VALUES(DATEADD(d, 6, @date), 1, 1,6)
```

and you want to calculate the correlation of X and Y for each group. Currently I use CTEs which get a little messy:

```
;WITH DataAvgStd
     AS (SELECT GroupID,
                AVG(X)   AS XAvg,
                AVG(Y)   AS YAvg,
                STDEV(X) AS XStdev,
                STDEV(Y) AS YSTDev,
                COUNT(*) AS SampleSize
         FROM   #sample
         GROUP  BY GroupID),
     ExpectedVal
     AS (SELECT s.GroupID,
                SUM(( X - XAvg ) * ( Y - YAvg )) AS ExpectedValue
         FROM   #sample s
                JOIN DataAvgStd das
                  ON s.GroupID = das.GroupID
         GROUP  BY s.GroupID)
SELECT das.GroupID,
       ev.ExpectedValue / ( das.SampleSize - 1 ) / ( das.XStdev * das.YSTDev )
       AS
       Correlation
FROM   DataAvgStd das
       JOIN ExpectedVal ev
         ON das.GroupID = ev.GroupID

DROP TABLE #sample
```

It seems like there should be a way to use OVER and PARTITION to do this in one fell swoop without any subqueries. Ideally TSQL would have a function so you could write:

```
SELECT GroupID, CORR(X, Y) OVER(PARTITION BY GroupID)
FROM #sample
GROUP BY GroupID
```

Comment: I'd be interested to see if anyone comes up with a viable solution, however, I always pull all my data to the business layer and perform correlations there. We also perform what we call "negative correlations" - where we skip positive values and only include negative values - it would also be interesting to see if this were viable in SQL.

Comment: The code you posted didn't execute for various reasons. I've changed it so it actually runs you might want to verify that it still does whatever you were expecting...

Comment: If X or Y are nullable, you need to replace "FROM   #sample" with "FROM   #sample WHERE X IS NOT NULL AND Y IS NOT NULL", otherwise you may end up with wrong correlation

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using this formula of corellation you cannot avoid all the nested queries even if you use `over()`. The thing is that you cannot use both group by and over in the same query and also you can not have nested aggregation functions e.g. `sum(x - avg(x))`. So you in best case scenario, according to your data, you will need to keep at least the `with`.

Your code will look like something like that

```
;WITH DataAvgStd
     AS (SELECT GroupID,
                STDEV(X) over(partition by GroupID) AS XStdev,
                STDEV(Y) over(partition by GroupID) AS YSTDev,
                COUNT(*) over(partition by GroupID) AS SampleSize,
                ( X - AVG(X) over(partition by GroupID)) * ( Y - AVG(Y) over(partition by GroupID)) AS ExpectedValue
         FROM   #sample s)         
SELECT distinct GroupID,
       SUM(ExpectedValue) over(partition by GroupID) / (SampleSize - 1 ) / ( XStdev * YSTDev ) AS Correlation
FROM DataAvgStd
```

An alternative is to use an equilevant formula for correlation as [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) describes.

This can be written as

```
SELECT GroupID,
       Correlation=(COUNT(*) * SUM(X * Y) - SUM(X) * SUM(Y)) / 
                   (SQRT(COUNT(*) * SUM(X * X) - SUM(X) * SUM(x))
                    * SQRT(COUNT(*) * SUM(Y* Y) - SUM(Y) * SUM(Y)))
FROM #sample s
GROUP BY GroupID;
```

Comment: The second formula you mention, where is it in the Wikipedia article? I don't quite see it.

Comment: @bpeikes It is the last formula in the `Pearson's product-moment coefficient` section.

Answer (score 4):

## A Single-Pass Solution for Both Calcs:

There are two flavors of the Pearson correlation coefficient, one for a Sample and one for an entire Population.  These are simple, single-pass, and I believe, correct formulas for both:

```
-- Methods for calculating the two Pearson correlation coefficients
SELECT  
        -- For Population
        (avg(x * y) - avg(x) * avg(y)) / 
        (sqrt(avg(x * x) - avg(x) * avg(x)) * sqrt(avg(y * y) - avg(y) * avg(y))) 
        AS correlation_coefficient_population,
        -- For Sample
        (count(*) * sum(x * y) - sum(x) * sum(y)) / 
        (sqrt(count(*) * sum(x * x) - sum(x) * sum(x)) * sqrt(count(*) * sum(y * y) - sum(y) * sum(y))) 
        AS correlation_coefficient_sample
    FROM (
        -- The following generates a table of sample data containing two columns with a luke-warm and tweakable correlation 
        -- y = x for 0 thru 99, y = x - 100 for 100 thru 199, etc.  Execute it as a stand-alone to see for yourself
        -- x and y are CAST as DECIMAL to avoid integer math, you should definitely do the same
        -- Try TOP 100 or less for full correlation (y = x for all cases), TOP 200 for a PCC of 0.5, TOP 300 for one near 0.33, etc.
        -- The superfluous "+ 0" is where you could apply various offsets to see that they have no effect on the results
        SELECT TOP 200
                CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1 + 0 AS DECIMAL) AS x, 
                CAST((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1) % 100 AS DECIMAL) AS y 
            FROM sys.all_objects
    ) AS a
```

As I noted in the comments, you can try the example with TOP 100 or less for full correlation (y = x for all cases); TOP 200 yields correlations very near 0.5; TOP 300, around 0.33; etc.  There is a place ("+ 0") to add an offset if you like; spoiler alert, it has no effect.  Make sure you CAST your values as DECIMAL - integer math can significantly impact these calcs.

Answer (score 1):

SQL get's a bit funny about nesting aggregates or windowing functions, hence the need for the CTEs or derived tables.

If it must be implemented on the DB server, and you are looking for something more readable than the CTEs your only option is to roll your own aggregate with CLR.

There is a good tutorial here http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQLCLR/71942/ on building a similar CLR aggregate.

Comment: Yeah. I don't know why anyone would want to do this in the "business" layer. You have to pull a ton of data out of the database to calculate correlations.
What I really don't understand is how SQL server doesn't have it as a built in. Seems like SQL server could do a much better job optimizing the numbers.